# How to display default filefield value when editing records in django?

Tags: django

I have a ModelForm with an additional filefield in it, now I can submit the form and the file is being uploaded the way I wanted also the records are being saved.

The problem is that when I'm editing, the filefield appears empty. How do I make it so it displays the current file uploaded on the record being edited?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `<input type="file" />` fields work that way. They are strictly upload only. If you were to put a value in it, when the form is submitted it would attempt to resolve that value to a local path on your computer and upload that file. A better solution would be to display the name of the file attached to the current record with static text, and only show the `<input type="file" />` field when uploading a new file.